# Filtering data frame depending on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have two data frames df and df2. I'd like to generate a new column in df by filtering df2, such that the filter depends on df. Instead one could use a for-loop, but that's quite slow for big data frames... Please look at the code.
Thanks a lot in advance

Fabian

```
#generating dummy data frames
df <- data.frame("var1" = 0:15)
df2 <- data.frame("var2" = 11:20, "var3" = 21:30)

# the following command unfortunatelly does not work
df$new_column <- df2 %>% filter(var2 > df$var1) %>% mean(var3)

# that's the output I want - but without a for-loop 
for (i in 1:length(df$var1)){
  h <- df2 %>% filter(var2 > df$var1[i])
  df$new_column[i] <- mean(h$var3)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply`, get all values in `df2` greater than each value in `var1` and take `mean` of it.

```
df$new_column <- sapply(df$var1, function(x) 
                 mean(df2$var3[df2$var2 > x], na.rm = TRUE))
df

#   var1 new_column
#1     0       25.5
#2     1       25.5
#3     2       25.5
#4     3       25.5
#5     4       25.5
#6     5       25.5
#7     6       25.5
#8     7       25.5
#9     8       25.5
#10    9       25.5
#11   10       25.5
#12   11       26.0
#13   12       26.5
#14   13       27.0
#15   14       27.5
#16   15       28.0
```

Or the same can be used with `map_dbl` from `purrr`

```
df$new_column <- purrr::map_dbl(df$var1,
                  ~mean(df2$var3[df2$var2 > .x], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That's (in my specific case) approximately 5 times faster than the solution with the for-loop!